# audio/mp4 files not playing on pre-lollipop devices

Tags: android, audio, mp4

I am trying to play this file:

```
 https://r2---sn-o097zne7.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?id=f7f0d0f6c9fc16f0&itag=141&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&nh=IgpwcjAxLnNqYzA3KgkxMjcuMC4wLjE&pl=21&mv=u&ms=au&mm=31&mn=sn-o097zne7&ratebypass=yes&mime=audio/mp4&gir=yes&clen=6859545&lmt=1393625541659713&dur=215.132&fexp=9408087,9408208,9408710,9413278,9416126,9416984,9417683,9418044,9418204,9419444,9419966,9420452,9422150,9422565,9422596,9422618,9422676,9423420,9423510,9423662,9423991,9424257,9424298,9424508&upn=fMq3m7OnpOU&sver=3&signature=4DD9C70769C99B2B769A9A4DEB2D2F750128D10A.7556708E037F26F71D430C20C897957676CBACB9&mt=1447923721&key=dg_yt0&ip=198.57.171.34&ipbits=0&expire=1447945674&sparams=ip,ipbits,expire,id,itag,source,requiressl,nh,pl,mv,ms,mm,mn,ratebypass,mime,gir,clen,lmt,dur
```

on a device with Android 4.2.2 but playback doesn't start. On the logs, i am getting the following messages;

```
    11-19 12:07:13.695 23678-23678/com.radioafrica.music V/MediaPlayer-JNI: reset
    11-19 12:07:13.695 23678-23678/com.radioafrica.music V/MediaPlayer: reset
    11-19 12:07:13.703 23678-23678/com.radioafrica.music V/MediaPlayer-JNI: setAudioStreamType: 3
    11-19 12:07:13.703 23678-23678/com.radioafrica.music V/MediaPlayer: MediaPlayer::setAudioStreamType
    11-19 12:07:13.718 23678-23678/com.radioafrica.music V/MediaPlayer: setVideoSurfaceTexture
    11-19 12:07:13.718 23678-23678/com.radioafrica.music V/MediaPlayer: prepareAsync
    11-19 12:07:26.203 23678-23689/com.radioafrica.music V/MediaPlayer: message received msg=3, ext1=3, ext2=0
    11-19 12:07:26.203 23678-23689/com.radioafrica.music V/MediaPlayer: buffering 3
    11-19 12:07:26.203 23678-23689/com.radioafrica.music V/MediaPlayer: callback application
    11-19 12:07:26.203 23678-23689/com.radioafrica.music V/MediaPlayer: back from callback
    11-19 12:07:26.203 23678-23689/com.radioafrica.music V/MediaPlayer: message received msg=200, ext1=973, ext2=0
    11-19 12:07:26.203 23678-23689/com.radioafrica.music W/MediaPlayer: info/warning (973, 0)
    11-19 12:07:26.203 23678-23689/com.radioafrica.music V/MediaPlayer: callback application
    11-19 12:07:26.203 23678-23689/com.radioafrica.music V/MediaPlayer: back from callback
    11-19 12:07:26.203 23678-23689/com.radioafrica.music V/MediaPlayer: message received msg=5, ext1=0, ext2=0
    11-19 12:07:26.203 23678-23689/com.radioafrica.music V/MediaPlayer: New video size 0 x 0
    11-19 12:07:26.203 23678-23689/com.radioafrica.music V/MediaPlayer: callback application
    11-19 12:07:26.203 23678-23689/com.radioafrica.music V/MediaPlayer: back from callback
    11-19 12:07:26.203 23678-23689/com.radioafrica.music V/MediaPlayer: message received msg=1, ext1=0, ext2=0
    11-19 12:07:26.203 23678-23689/com.radioafrica.music V/MediaPlayer: prepared
    11-19 12:07:26.203 23678-23689/com.radioafrica.music V/MediaPlayer: callback application
    11-19 12:07:26.203 23678-23689/com.radioafrica.music V/MediaPlayer: back from callback
    11-19 12:07:26.203 23678-23678/com.radioafrica.music I/MediaPlayer: Info (973,0)
    11-19 12:07:26.203 23678-23678/com.radioafrica.music I/MediaPlayer: Don't send intent. msg.arg1 = 0, msg.arg2 = 0
    11-19 12:07:26.203 23678-23678/com.radioafrica.music V/MediaPlayer-JNI: setVolume: left 1.000000  right 1.000000
    11-19 12:07:26.203 23678-23678/com.radioafrica.music V/MediaPlayer: MediaPlayer::setVolume(1.000000, 1.000000)
    11-19 12:07:26.210 23678-23678/com.radioafrica.music V/MediaPlayer: isPlaying: 0
    11-19 12:07:26.210 23678-23678/com.radioafrica.music V/MediaPlayer-JNI: isPlaying: 0
    11-19 12:07:26.210 23678-23678/com.radioafrica.music V/MediaPlayer-JNI: start
    11-19 12:07:26.210 23678-23678/com.radioafrica.music V/MediaPlayer: start
    11-19 12:07:26.414 23678-23690/com.radioafrica.music V/MediaPlayer: message received msg=2, ext1=0, ext2=0
    11-19 12:07:26.414 23678-23690/com.radioafrica.music V/MediaPlayer: playback complete
    11-19 12:07:26.414 23678-23690/com.radioafrica.music V/MediaPlayer: callback application
    11-19 12:07:26.414 23678-23690/com.radioafrica.music V/MediaPlayer: back from callback
    11-19 12:07:27.203 23678-23689/com.radioafrica.music V/MediaPlayer: message received msg=3, ext1=3, ext2=0
    11-19 12:07:27.203 23678-23689/com.radioafrica.music V/MediaPlayer: buffering 3
    11-19 12:07:27.203 23678-23689/com.radioafrica.music V/MediaPlayer: callback application
    11-19 12:07:27.203 23678-23689/com.radioafrica.music V/MediaPlayer: back from callback
```

It seems that the files does buffer but doesn't start playing, instead, the player calls playback complete and skips to the next song.

However, the file plays with no  problem on Android 5 and above. What could be problem?

This the player code:

```
try {
//manualUrl is the link mentioned above
                    if (manualUrl != null) {
                        createMediaPlayerIfNeeded();
                        mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                        mPlayer.setDataSource(manualUrl);
                        mIsStreaming = manualUrl.startsWith("http:") || manualUrl.startsWith("https:");
                mSongTitle = track.getTitle();
                mSongArtist = track.getArtist();

                //mState = State.Preparing;
                PrefUtils.putString(PrefUtils.STATE, PREPARING);

                MediaButtonHelper.registerMediaButtonEventReceiverCompat(
                        mAudioManager, mMediaButtonReceiverComponent);

                if (mRemoteControlClientCompat == null) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
                    intent.setComponent(mMediaButtonReceiverComponent);

                    mRemoteControlClientCompat = new RemoteControlClientCompat(
                            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MusicService.this, 0, intent, 0));

                    RemoteControlHelper.registerRemoteControlClient(mAudioManager,
                            mRemoteControlClientCompat);
                }

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
                    mRemoteControlClientCompat.setPlaybackState(RemoteControlClient.PLAYSTATE_PLAYING);

                    mRemoteControlClientCompat.setTransportControlFlags(
                            RemoteControlClient.FLAG_KEY_MEDIA_PLAY |
                                    RemoteControlClient.FLAG_KEY_MEDIA_PAUSE |
                                    RemoteControlClient.FLAG_KEY_MEDIA_NEXT |
                                    RemoteControlClient.FLAG_KEY_MEDIA_STOP);
                }

                mRemoteControlClientCompat.editMetadata(true)
                        .putString(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST, track.getArtist())
                        .putString(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM, "")
                        .putString(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, track.getTitle())
                        .apply();

                mPlayer.prepareAsync();

                if (mIsStreaming)
                    mWifiLock.acquire();
                else if (mWifiLock.isHeld())
                    mWifiLock.release();

                sendBroadcast(mSongTitle, "Loading...", true);

                if (duration != 0) {
                    Music.setCurrentTrackDuration(duration);
                }
            } else {
                playSong(Music.getCurrentPlaylist(), true);

                Toast.makeText(MusicService.this, "Track unavailable, playing next tune.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException | SecurityException | IOException | IllegalStateException | NullPointerException e) {
            playSong(Music.getCurrentPlaylist(), true);
            Toast.makeText(MusicService.this, "Track unavailable, playing next tune.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Can we see you code ?

Comment: @CyprienAubry check updated question

Comment: Does that exact same link still work now? I ask because it looks like it has an expiry time (which is a typical link protection used by "that" server). Also it seems to expect request from an **HTTPS** location?? All I know is "that" server expects a browser's user-agent before releasing any audio/video bytes (ie: their own player is usually embedded in a web-page and thus it's able to load the a/v data). Maybe Android 5 automatically adds a user-agent for any HTTP url's? Anyways I don't even use Android. I saw MP4 and assumed an **MPEG codec** issue but really it's Android file access issue